# Some Simple Translation Sentences Involving Key Grammar Phrases: 是， 像， 过 ， Direction Phrases

Tags: translation, writing-critique

I was wondering if someone could make sure my translations for these sentences are correct.
Thank you very much. Use

1. The book I'm reading now is a birthday gift given by a friend. Use 是

   > 我现在读的书是朋友送给我的生日礼物。
2. The person who asked you to dance looked like my friend when he smiled. Use 像

   > 那个请你跳舞的人笑的时候看起来像我的朋友。
3. We've met before, but we've never spoke to each other. Use 过， 见面，说话，从来没

   > 我们之前见过面，但是我们从来没跟彼此说话。
4. The place I live is to the north of the student center. Use 的地方，在。。。的北边

   > 我住的地方在学生中心的北边。
5. The language lab is inside the building to the south of the computer center. Use 语言实验室， 计算机几种心，在，南侧

   I'm not sure how to translate this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

祝你中秋节快乐！

My attempt:

```
1. The book I'm reading now is a birthday gift given by a friend Use 是
```

Yours: 我现在读的书是朋友送给我的生日礼物。
Mine: 我现在在看/读的小说是朋友给我的生日礼物。

```
2. The person who asked you to dance looked like my friend when he smiled. Use 像
```

Yours: 那个请你跳舞的人笑的时候看起来像我的朋友。
Mine: 那个邀请你跳舞的人笑起来的时侯好像我的朋友。

```
3. We've met before, but we've never spoke to each other. Use 过， 见面，说话，从来没
```

Yours: 我们之前见过面，但是我们从来没跟彼此说话。
Mine: 我们以前见过面，但是从来没和对方说过话。

```
4. The place I live is to the north of the student center. Use 的地方，在。。。的北边
```

Yours: 我住的地方在学生中心的北边。
Mine: 我住的地方在“学生中心”的北边。

```
5. The language lab is inside the building to the south of the computer center. Use 语言实验室，
```

Yours:
Mine: 语言实验室在“电脑中心”南边的那栋楼里面。

Answer (score 0):

1 perfect
2 good.  option: 那个请你跳舞的人笑的时候好像我的朋友.
3 good.  option: 我们之前见过面，但是我们从来没说过话。
4 perfect.  Simple reminder: 的 can be omitted in location.
5 Quite a headache because not sure this is campus direction (rather formal): 视听教室 (or 视听中心)在计算机中心南边 (or 南侧) 的建筑 (can be 大楼, dpends) 里。 or just pointing to peers :  视听教室在电脑中心南边的大楼里。